# POST to Laravel 4 Controller from Chrome for Android not working

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel

I have a Controller and View set up to send a POST request to the server.  Very simple, common operation.  Well, when I test on desktop in Chrome, I have no issue, the POST data gets sent, the database gets loaded correctly, and the page redirects as it should.  When I test in Chrome on Android, however, it seems to perform a GET operation instead; it responds with what I have in the `show` function, and nothing gets loaded to the database.  Testing in Firefox on the same phone works fine.  Is this an issue with Chrome on Android, or is there something else I should be checking?

```
// controller
public function update($id)
{
    $roomevent = Roomevent::find($id);
    $roomevent->description = Input::get('description');
    $roomevent->room_id = Input::get('room_id');
    $roomevent->save();
    Session::flash('message', 'Saved successfully');
    return Redirect::to('/roomevent');
}

public function show($id)
{
    echo "This was GET";  // here's what i see on Android/Chrome
}


//view
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
   {{ Form::model($roomevent, array('route' => array('roomevent.update', $roomevent->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
      @include('roomevent.form')
   {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Looking in the HTML source when the page is loaded, I am seeing POST showing as the method in the `<form>` tag.  I think I can assume it's POST on the mobile browser too, but Chrome for Android doesn't let you view source.  What could the problem be?

Comment: How it behaves on POSTMAN ?

Comment: It greatly discourages me from posting here when I get downvoted, taking away what little reputation I already have, without so much as a suggestion for how I can improve the question.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, I didn't try with Postman because it's not a POSTing issue, POST works fine.  The issue is that Chrome for Android does not even do a POST, it does a GET instead, even though POST is set in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this issue resolved itself, not sure if it was a Chrome bug or a phone restart -- so my simple answer is, update Chrome, then restart your phone.